# Netbeans system.out.println issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans, system.out, netbeans-8

I am running a spring mvc web application and when I run it all works fine in the browser on the glassfish server. but in some of the code there is system.out.println and they will not show up in the console. 
there is just a line saying BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 54 seconds)

how can I get the console to complete the system.out.println pieces of code whenever I interact with the browser.

for example on one of the jsps I have a question with 4 radio button options. when i click the submit button I want the netbeans console to print out which one I have chosen.

i.e. just run this code:

```
if(request.getParameter("radios") != null) {
                if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("Int")) {
                    model.addAttribute("score", 0);
                    res.add(0);
                    System.out.println("Int selected as your answer");
                }
                else if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("Enum")) {
                    model.addAttribute("score", 0);
                    res.add(0);
                    System.out.println("Enum selected as your answer");
                }
                else if(request.getParameter("radios").equals("integer1")) {
                    model.addAttribute("score", 0);
                    res.add(0);
                    System.out.println("integer was selected as your answer");
                }
                else {
                    model.addAttribute("score", 1);
                    res.add(1);
                    System.out.println("Integer was selected as your answer");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of pedantry, but use logging. Beside `java.util.logging`, a servlet (like a JSP) has a `log` method. Logging is also saved a log file in general, which helps, when time passes after an error report is received.

Systen.out not appearing might be due to `System.setOut` capturing the output, in general to a log too. Maybe look in the glassfish logs.

The other case might be an Exception being thrown. For instance when there is no parameter radios. But that would probably show.

It might also be that you run glassfish as a service, and so there is an inaccessible System.out.
Not likely in the combination NetBeans + Glassfish.

Comment: surely there is more simple solution. im certain when I use to use Eclipse (before it broke), every time you interacted with a jsp in the browser then something would be written to the console. logging will surely take a long time to set up? and like you said will be pedantry

Comment: Try `System.out.println("radios: " + request.getParameter("radios"));` - or debug with breakpoint. To look whether you reach that spot.